# Update every row in a table by setting a column to the sum of two other columns in MySql

Tags: mysql

Say i have the following table in mysql:

Table: `height_storage`

```
|----|--------|--------|--------------|
| id | height | buffer | total_height |
|----|--------|--------|--------------|
| 0  | 120    | 100    |              |
| 1  | 180    | 120    |              |
| ...                                 |
|----|--------|--------|--------------|
```

I'm trying to find a way to run a single query that will update every row in the table by setting `total_height` to the value of `height + buffer`.

It should end up looking like this after the query is run

```
|----|--------|--------|--------------|
| id | height | buffer | total_height |
|----|--------|--------|--------------|
| 0  | 120    | 100    | 220          |
| 1  | 180    | 120    | 300          |
| ...                                 |
|----|--------|--------|--------------|
```

Comment: Why do you want to store redundant data. And what is your MySQL version?

Comment: show which query you tried so far

Comment: @PaulSpiegel This is an example, the actual database is a little more complicated than this. MySql server version is 5.7.21

Comment: In 5.7 you can define a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do an UPDATE with a sum of the two elements:

```
UPDATE height_storage
set total_height=height+buffer
```

But you may need to set the safe mode off before using the query, because you are not using a WHERE clause and not using a key:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE height_storage
set total_height=height+buffer
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted, this is the correct answer. However, I'd add that instead of using `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` you should use a catch-all `WHERE`. Like `WHERE height > -1 AND buffer > -1` (assuming that that catch-all works for your table).